# ROS2 Custom Messages Not Found

Tags: ros2, colcon, ros-bouncy, rclpy, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to run my python script, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightring_msgs'`. I know the message types are being generated; the package files are in the install directory. Why can't python find the module?

My project layout

```
/lightring_driver
    /lightring_driver
        <driver files>
        package.xml
        setup.cfg
        setup.py
    /lightring_msgs
        /msg
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
        setup.cfg
```

lightring_msgs/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(lightring_msgs)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(lightring_msgs
  "msg/LightringCommand.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES builtin_interfaces
)

ament_package()
```

lightring_msgs/package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format2.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>lightring_msgs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="jacob@todo.todo">jacob</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <depend>builtin_interfaces</depend>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306568/ros2-custom-messages-not-found/) by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-25**:
How are you building these packages? did you source the `setup.bash`/`setup.bat` file after building? Is the location that you installed to on your `PYTHONPATH` as a result?

**Comment by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) on 2018-10-25**:
Looks like not sourcing `setup.sh` (in my case) was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot to source `install/setup.sh` after building. Thanks @William!

---

Originally posted by [beck](https://answers.ros.org/users/38178/beck/) with karma: 121 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1